# How do you read data like tables from SQL Developer using Grails?

Tags: grails, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have fair amount of knowledge of Grails but I cannot find a way how to read data from a table from sql developers using Grails. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you use `run-app`, the database is in-memory (the url is something like "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"), so there's no way to connect to it from outside the JVM. If you change it to a "real" database you can connect to it from both Grails and another client.

To do this with H2, one option is to start a standalone server. This requires that you find the H2 jar - it will be under $HOME/.m2/repository or $HOME/.grails/ivy-cache. For example on my machine the command to start on port 9092 (the default) is

```
java -cp /home/burt/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.3.170/h2-1.3.170.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9092
```

Then change the url in `grails-app/conf/DataSource` to

```
url = 'jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/dbname'
```

where "dbname" is arbitrary - H2 supports creating multiple databases per server. You can then start Grails and it will connect to that server, and you can connect from another client too.

A simpler way to do this is to use H2's auto-server mode, e.g. with this url

```
url = 'jdbc:h2:./dbname;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=9092'
```

it will start up an in-memory database but with a TCP socket on port 9092 that you can connect to externally. This avoids having to find the jar and explicitly start the database server.

See http://h2database.com/html/main.html for more configuration information.

You can also use a different server, e.g. a MySQL/PostgreSQL/Oracle/etc server.

But having said all this, there is a convenient database client already running that you can access. When you start Grails with `run-app` you can connect to `http://localhost:8080/appname/dbconsole` in a web browser and access your table information, do SQL queries, etc. This is an H2 feature, but it works with whatever database you use since it works with JDBC, so you can use it with MySQL or whatever. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#databaseConsole for more information on this.